# How to set "clipboard copymode= disable" to frozen columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I don't want to copy the values from `datagridview` frozen columns. Only i can able to copy Unfrozen columns. How to resolve it?

Comment: Who is doing the copying? the user or your program?

Comment: Only User can copy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a property for that in the `DGV` or its `Cells`. But in the `EditingControl` there is:

```
// subscribe to the event that goes with entering edit mode:
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
                           DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    // get a reference to the currently showing edit control:
    DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb = DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl) e.Control;

    // disallow the standard actions
    tb.ShortcutsEnabled = 
      !dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Frozen;

}
```

We also need to disallow keyboard copying without entering edit mode:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Frozen) 
        e.Handled = true;
}
```